# Using Karate with Gradle but without (Java)-Runner

Tags: karate

I'm trying to use Karate and therefore created a `.feature` and a `config.properties` file. Of course I don't want to check-in the sources of Karate in each project, so I'd like to use Gradle to download Karate and run it afterwards.

Unfortunately, I can't manage to make it work. My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.properties.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('features')
            include 'rest.feature'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.7.0'
  testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.7.0'
}

wrapper {
  gradleVersion = 4.6
}
```

When I run `./gradlew test -Dtest=<featureName>` the `.feature` file just gets copied to `build/resources/test` instead of running the suite.

Could you please show me how to set it up correctly? I wouldn't want to use a Java class with the `@RunWith(Karate.class)` annotation because that would be unnecessary boiler-plate code in each project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think you *should* use the Java class because you get the advantage of the [dev-mode JUnit report](https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report) - but that's just my 2c.

I am not a Gradle expert by any means, but this Gradle example from the community may help you figure out if you have missed anything: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/build.gradle

It has a few un-necessary dependencies which you should ignore of course.

EDIT: Just realized you are expecting to run the feature without *any* Java runner, sorry that's not possible from the command line. You can "right-click-and-run" from IntelliJ and Eclipse (with the right plugin installed, refer the doc) - and this is what most teams do on a daily basis.

If you do some research you should be able to write *one* Java class that can take a command line arg or system property and run the feature you specify. And again IMHO a Java runner is far more convenient (less typing) or just use the IDE support.